# Windows 7 cannot access shared folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive

Recently a Windows XP system's hardware got failed, so I put its harddisk to a new system which was working fine.

I have the windows 7 system from which I want to access that Windows XP's shared drive.

Before the Windows XP system failure, I was able to connect to the it from the Windows 7 system, but after the Xp failure, whenever I try to connect to it, then it doesnt accepts my username & password & shows the message "`Access is denied`".

I dont understand why it is not getting connected even I am using the same Hard disk with the same OS ?

Comment: "so I put its harddisk to a new system which was working fine" as a secondary drive?

Comment: No, as a primary drive.

Comment: once i have seen that time should be correct on both machines. The connectivity is ok between machines?

Comment: @emirjonb, Yes time was wrong on that XP machine but after I corrected it also, not working.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly: you had windows XP machine which broke down, so you pulled HDD and put it into new machine? If yes, it won't work. XP does hash check on hardware each time it boots to prevent unlicensed use of a system.

I am surprised you can even boot this new setup at all. Are you sure the XP machine is up and running?

If somehow yes, then maybe you're using the same share defined in windows 7. In that case it won't work as well, because what you have is essentially new network shared folder and what you have on Win7 machine points to old one. You have to connect to it as it would be different shared resource.

Comment: XP machine is running fine. It is asking for username & password but showing `access is denied` error after entering correct username & password.

Comment: Is it when logging locally or via network? If via network, you need to first log in locally or via RDP and check if the resource you're trying to access is shared properly with adequate permissions for the account you're using... If it's locally, then you need local admin credentials and then again: go check account you're trying to log in. The error you get is clearly security-connected.

Comment: I can login locally. Problem is when login via network. I also checked the directory sharing status. It is shared as before.

Comment: "Access is denied" clearly points you to security on XP. Please check sharing permissions again. If all is ok, unshare and then share again. Make sure the account you're using to log in has permissions to shared resource.